# Keras Layers Unintentionally Sharing Variables

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I am building a CNN model that takes in two sources of data: (1) 1D lidar data, and (2) RGB images. To combine the two sources, I do the following. First, I extract features from the 1D lidar data using several convolutional layers with batch norm, for example ...

```
    with tf.variable_scope("lidar_model"):
        base_model = OrderedDict()
        base_model['input'] = Input(shape=(input_size, 1))
        base_model['conv_1'] = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=7, strides=3, padding='valid', activation=None)(base_model['input'])
        base_model['batch_norm_1'] = BatchNormalization()(base_model['conv_1'])
        base_model['activation_1'] = Activation(activation='relu')(base_model['batch_norm_1'])  

        base_model['max_pool_1'] = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, padding='same')(base_model['activation_1'])

        base_model['conv_2'] = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation=None)(base_model['max_pool_1'])
        base_model['batch_norm_2'] = BatchNormalization()(base_model['conv_2'])
        base_model['activation_2'] = Activation(activation='relu')(base_model['batch_norm_2'])
```

I also extract features from the images using ResNet50:

```
   with tf.variable_scope("image_model"):    
        feature_extractor = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max')
```

Finally, I combine the features by concatenating the outputs of the two models above, and pass through several dense layers.

My problem is the following. Visualizing my model in tensorboard, it appears that the **convolutional** and **batch normalization** layers in the lidar model are sharing variables with the ResNet model. For example, the *gamma*, *beta*, *moving_mean*, and *moving_variance* variables inside the lidar batch norm layers are output to the ResNet model. The *kernel* and the *bias* from the lidar convolutional layers are also passed to the ResNet model. It is unclear exactly where these tensors end up going, but a group of lidar model tensors appear to be feeding into all the batch normalization layers inside ResNet.

Here are the relevant images:

[Two Models Sharing Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vbg0.png)
You will see tensors being shared from lidar model (base_scan_model) to image model (rendered_path_model).

[Batch Norm and Conv Layers in Lidar Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Dzy.png)
You will see several erroneous things. (1) batch norm layers are sharing variables with each other and outputting to ResNet, (2) conv layers are also outputting to ResNet.

[ResNet Example Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqVug.png)
You will see tensors coming from the lidar model into the batch norm layers of ResNet, which should not be.

**How do I enforce Keras/Tensorflow to keep the two models separate**, so that no tensors are output from the lidar model to ResNet? Using tf.variable_scope() does not appear to achieve this.

I find the same error regardless if I am using tensorflow 1.2 and keras 2.1.5, or using strictly tensorflow 1.7.

Comment: This sounds unbelievable. I have created `BatchNormalization()` and `ResNet50()` side by side without additional scopes and they don't share anything. Provide some evidence variables are shared

Comment: Hi Maxim, I just updated my post to include images as requested. As you can see, there are tensors being passed from the lidar model (base_scan_model) to the ResNet model (rendered_path_model). Let me know if you need additional information.